# Eclipse show errors when include jsp in another jsp (fragments)

Tags: eclipse, jsp

In Spring-MVC Web App, I have a structure like in a screen. Inside `webapp/WEB-INF` is folder `jsp`. Some `jsp` files are included in every site, these jsp are in subfolder `parts`, when I run applications, `head,footer and header` are visible on site.

[image]

But Eclipse shows errors in jsp editor: `Fragment "/parts/footer" was not found at expected path /blog/src/main/webapp/parts/footer`. In web.xml is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How configure Eclipse to fix this annoying error?

**----------Edited 2014-04-09---------**

I found what is a problem. The problem is Maven dependency. This Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I add it to `pom.xml` then eclipse show errors like above. When I comment it, clean genereted files (`.project, .classpath, target, .settings`), and one more time import to eclipse, looks ok. Any idea whats is wrong with maven dependencies?
[Here](https://github.com/tostao/simple-spring-mvc) is a src of this project.

Comment: Um, why would you map all the jsps under `/WEB-INF/jsp/*` like that?  It defeats the whole purpose of putting them under /WEB-INF/.

Answer (score 0):

I think your include directive is wrong.  The JSP compiler is off looking for these kids relative to the root of your context and you have them buried way down underneath WEB-INF (which as @developerwjk mentioned is unconventional, at best).  If you make the includes relative, does the red go away?

```
<jsp:include page="parts/footer.jsp"/>
```

Our Spring-MVC project was structured like

```
bobk-mbp:hubimport bobk$ tree
.
├── WebContent
│   ├── META-INF
│   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   ├── WEB-INF
│   │   ├── c.tld
│   │   ├── classes
...
│   │   ├── lib
...
│   │   └── web.xml
│   ├── jsp
│   │   ├── about.jsp
│   │   ├── assetError.jsp
│   │   ├── assetList.jsp
│   │   ├── assetUpload.jsp
│   │   ├── common.js
│   │   ├── contentUploading.jsp
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── logo.gif
│   │   ├── hubimporter.css
│   │   ├── index.jsp
│   │   ├── menu.jsp
│   │   └── wait_gif.gif
│   └── scripts
│       ├── imgpreview.min.0.22.jquery.js
│       └── jquery-1.7.min.js
├── src
│   ├── c.tld
│   ├── com
...
```

And each JSP included the menu.jsp like

```
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to map the JSPs in web.xml is actually wrong.  You would not reference /WEB-INF/ in the `url-pattern` but in the `jsp-file` tag.  /WEB-INF/ cannot be used as a url-pattern because by definition, Tomcat will not serve anything under WEB-INF unless its mapped to a different url-pattern.  WEB-INF is sort of for hiding things.

Below only maps one JSP, but it gives the basic idea.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jspinwebinftest</servlet-name> 
  <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsptest.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jspinwebinftest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/jspinwebinftest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You would then include the file via the url pattern.

The point of hiding JSPs under WEB-INF is if you don't want them to be accessible via their filenames (whatever.jsp) because its impossible for the user to access /WEB-INF/whatever.jsp since nothing under /WEB-INF/ is served unless mapped to another url. So you would put your jsp under WEB-INF if you want it to be mapped like servlets (or like paths with no extensions, or different extensions than .jsp).  If you want them to be accessible by their regular file names, do not put them under WEB-INF.